# Using Arduino as a pc remote controller

Tags: serial

I would like to create a simple remote controller (IR) with my Arduino Nano that would control my PC. (Volume up/down, stop, play and that sort of things...) 
I have no problem with creating 'hardware part' and Arduino script, that would send commands through serial as a reaction to IR signals.
I can imagine python script that would react to commands received on the serial port.

My problem is: "How can I detect on which port should I listen to?" What is the right way to do it?

Comment: What operating system is on the computer?

Comment: And following a different route, could you have the device  emulate a USB keyboard? Many Arduino-like devices can do that. There are standard keys for play, volume etc.

Comment: @MarkSmith The arduino Leonardo has that ability, though I have never used it, and cannot speak to it's functionality.

Comment: Both Linux and Windows I guess, though Windows will be the preferred one.

Comment: i used node.js to monitor the serial port. based on the it codes coming in, it would execute small EXEs made with autohotkey to press keys/combos like VOL_UP.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks a lot. I can do that with python as well, only question is, how does the script which port to listen to... :(

Comment: well, when i re-assigned the "ftdi"'s COM port in windows, it stuck as COM10, even after rebooting, so that part was easy for me. there might be better ways, that's just what i got running one sunday...

Comment: @dandavis I ended up hoping that the COM port will stay the same. (If not, really easy to change port in python script)

Answer (score 1):

Since I can not commemnt due to low reputation, I'm "commenting" here. 
You can search for LIRC and WinLIRC